# Testing a mvn shaded plugin superjar, with included/excluded classes, from another Maven project

Tags: java, maven

I have a maven build configuration which includes some classes, and excludes a bunch of dependencies that we do not want contained in the shaded jar.

The build works fine, and we have an executable jar. I now have another maven project, containing a suite of tests, which is dependant on the Maven project with the shaded plugin.

I would like to test the shaded jar is able to run my suite of tests. However:

1. When I run as a maven install/exec, the dependency is not from the shaded jar and includes classes I have specifically removed
2. When I package the shaded jar, and the suite of tests, the suite of tests pulls from the m2 repository, and contains the classes I have specifically removed.

How can I test my jar from a maven command? 
Thanks

**EDIT -**

My integration tests include three dependencies, all of which are used to run end to end tests. For clarity, my project structure is like this :

```
integration-tests (cucumber test suite)
  |_ module 1 (executable jar with custom dependency inclusion/exclusion)
    |_ module 4
    |_ module 5
  |_ module 2 (executable jar)
  |_ module 3 (executable jar)
```

When I build and run integration tests, the dependency for module 1 is taken from the m2 repo. I would actually like to run the tests against the packaged jar, with the included/excluded classes, to ensure it works properly after mvn package has removed the exclusions.

**EDIT 2 -**

I have added an integration test to the project (of junit type). This runs successfully as the maven integration-test phase. However, when i remove some classes required by the tests from the maven-shade-plugin includes list, the tests still pass (running after package).

How can I test that the integration will run successfully in the shaded jar ? Do I need to setup a test to actually start and test output from the jar?

Comment: Sorry, I cannot completely follow you? Do you have a project that _depends_  on an executable jar?

Comment: Apologies if i was not very clear.. I have a project (1) which is used to create an executable jar. And another project (2) which runs tests on project 1. This works fine. When I package project 1 into an executable jar, I only include a select few classes.. Now, I was wondering if I could use project 2 to see if the executable jar is runnable (via the test suite). I was hoping perhaps I could inject the executable jar as a dependency.

Comment: Why don't you do this in the integration test phase of project (1)?

Comment: This could be what I am looking for after some investigation.. So if I run the tests in project 2 during integration test phase of project 1, the tests will correctly use the packaged jar?

Comment: The main issue I see is that project 2 lists project 1 as a dependency. But I'd like to run the tests in project 2 during project 1's integration test phase. Potentially causing a cyclic dependency, unless there is another way

Comment: Couldn't you just move the tests from project2 to project1? Then you configure the failsafe plugin to run them. The integration test phases are _after_ the jar is constructed.

Comment: I have added an explanation why to the question, the tests actually need 3 dependencies to run successfully. In fact, project 1 does not even include src code, it is merely a maven project used to package dependencies and remove unwanted classes

Comment: I still don't see why you can't include the tests into project1. You add the tests to `src/test/java`, configure the maven failsafe plugin accordingly, and you add the necessary dependencies as `test` dependencies, so that they are not included into the final (executable) jar.

Comment: Because this would be cyclic dependencies. Which project should build first could become confusing. I am going to add a separate suite of tests for this project, and run these in the integration phase. I dont believe its possible to use my existing tests as I would like

Comment: Cyclic dependencies between what? If you don't have project2 any more, what are the cyclic dependencies?

Comment: sorry, i obviously have not explained my project structure well enough. i have updated my question